# Fallback in expression syntax

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, github-actions

I have a github workflow that runs on two different events: pull_request and manually. It looks like this:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
  workflow_dispatch: {}

env:
  API_URL: https://example.com/
```

What I want is to be able to set an alternate `API_URL` when I trigger the workflow manually. But I want the workflow to run the same when it runs automatically.
So, first, I add “`inputs`” to the workflow_dispatch:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [master]
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      API_URL:
        description:
        required: true
        default: https://example.com

env:
  API_URL: ${{ github.event.API_URL }}
```

From what I understand, this way the `API_URL` env variable will only be set when the workflow is run manually. But when it’s run automatically, there’s no `github.event.API_URL` value.

It seems to me that a conditional fallback here is needed.
Will something like this work?

```yaml
env:
  API_URL: ${{ github.event.API_URL || 'https://example.com/' }}
```

But from the docs the `||` operator will evaluate to `1` or `0`.

Is there a good way to solve this? Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

This worked for me:

```
env:
  BRANCH: ${{ github.base_ref || 'devel' }}
```

Comment: This is viable only if you do not need to distinguish between first part being undefined or false. If it genuinely set to false you cannot use `||` construct to achieve different behavior than for undefined case.

Comment: @sorin If you know that the variable is a boolean you can use `${{ github.boolvar == true }}` or `${{ ! github.boolvar == false }}` for the opposite default (not tested)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately (at the time of writing this), it's not possible that way. But you can achieve the same effect by  [setting the environment variable](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/reference/workflow-commands-for-github-actions#setting-an-environment-variable) (`API_URL`) to the default value dynamically only when the job is **not** run manually (eg. the job is triggered by the PR event). You can do that by creating a conditional job step that will run only if `API_URL` has not been set yet:

```yaml
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      API_URL:
        required: true
        default: https://example.com
jobs:
  build:
    env:
      API_URL: ${{ github.event.inputs.API_URL }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Set API_URL environment variable
        if: env.API_URL == null
        run: echo "API_URL=https://example.com" >> $GITHUB_ENV
      - name: Test API_URL environment variable
        run: echo "API_URL=$API_URL"
```

This way we will have `API_URL` environment variable set regardless of the way the workflow was triggered (either manually or automatically) with the ability to override it with a custom value when run manually.

Comment: Thanks, I will try that

This doesn't look like a good solution though. First, you need to duplicate the default value in "inputs" and in "steps". Second, it will get cumbersome to add a step for each env value.

But thank you very much, this is still a solution, and I will try it